# acrobat javascript when checkbox is checked, make separate field required

Tags: javascript, checkbox, conditional-statements, acrobat, required

Being a designer, not a coder, I have limited coding ability.
I have created an acrobat form with a number of due date fields. They are only required if a corresponding checkbox is checked.

What is the javascript to say that 'if ***checkbox A*** is checked, then make ***date field A*** required'?

Also, do I save this as a document javascript, or link it to the checkbox?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after more searching, I pieced together the following script to add to the checkbox Properties, on MouseUp, add javascript as follows:

```
{if (this.getField("checkbox name here").isBoxChecked(0) == true) 
this.getField("required field name here").required = event.target.value!="On";
}
{if (this.getField("checkbox name here").isBoxChecked(0) == false) 
this.getField("required field name here").required = event.target.value!="Off";
}
```